# Adding integers dynamically as user inputs in dynamically created textboxes - Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started learning Angular JS and want to create a simple calculator. The user is first asked to enter the number of operands. After this I want to display those many numbers of textboxes for entering the operands. Below is the html(this is not the full code for the calculator) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="myCalc">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Calculator</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="FormController">
    <h3><em>Do your calculations here!!</em></h3>
    <div>        
        <p>Enter number of operands : <input type="number" ng-model="paramCount" name="count" ng-change="getNumber(paramCount)"/></p>
        <p ng-repeat="i in getNumber(paramCount)">Enter the operand : <input type="text" ng-model="numbers"/></p>
        <p><button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button></p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and below is the script:

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script> 
    var myCalcApp = angular.module('myCalc', []);

    myCalcApp.controller('FormController', function ($scope) {

        $scope.paramCount = 0;
        $scope.getNumber = function (num) {
            array = [];
            for (i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
                array.push(i)
            }
            return array;
        }
        $scope.reset = function () {                
            $scope.paramCount = 0;
        };
    });
</script>
```

I am stuck at binding the user input to any model and using it to calculate the sum.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to :

1) Create an array of operands in your controller.

Example : $scope.operands = [];

2) Initialize it in your "$scope.getNumber" function

3) Change this ng-model:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="numbers"/>
```

By this one :

```
<input type="text" ng-model="operands[$index]"/>
```

I hope my answer fit you.

Some useful doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat